# Xamarin Forms Android NoSupportedException while UWP works

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I recently updated my solution to latest nuget packages of Xamarin.Forms (2.3.4.267).  Now I receive an exception while I run my program in an Android Emulator (X86)

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
```

With this piece of code:

```
public virtual void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    if (collection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collection));

    foreach (var i in collection) Items.Add(i);
    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
}
```

And in particular, the line

```
foreach (var i in collection) Items.Add(i);
```

Here is a github link to test the problem
https://github.com/hugoterelle/posexclusive-droid-notsupported

Comment: I cant reproduced your problem, could you please post more complete code to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT sorry for the delay, I needed time to cleanup the solution in order to provide a github repo.  You can find it in the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to [an issue](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57919) I've encountered while working on Xamarin Android. This issue has been fixed on [release 15.3.2 of Xamarin](https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-15-3-2/).

Try updating your Xamarin version and try again

Comment: I didn't forget but you have to wait about 20 hours before I can award the bounty :)

Comment: Gawd, so much rules :) !